# Highcharts - highcharts-3d.js:16 Uncaught TypeError: O is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Hi I'm facing an issue with 3D Pie Chart using highchart.js

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/3d-pie/

-
highcharts-3d.js:16 Uncaught TypeError: O is not a function

```
$('#container').highcharts
({
    chart: {
        type: 'pie',
        options3d: {
            enabled: true,
            alpha: 45,
            beta: 0
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2014'
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            depth: 35,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.name}'
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Browser share',
        data: [
        {name:'Firefox', 
        y:45},

        {name:'Firefox123', 
        y:10}
        ]
    }]
});
```

any advice? thanks.

---

Fixed by downloading and changing all source file to latest version.

Comment: For me working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/aaotngrb/ , how can I replicate your issue?

Comment: Hello I realize that it was due to the version of my charts, it uses new phrases when my script version does not have these phrases.